# Error: Unable to find conda binary. Is Anaconda installed? reticulate Rstudio

Tags: python, r, anaconda, reticulate

I installed reticulate via Rstudio. Now i want to use `conda_create()` but I installed anaconda in another directory then the default. How can I change the directory in which Rstudio is searching for anaconda?

```
Error: Unable to find conda binary. Is Anaconda installed?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory should be in your path. But you can check where it is like this:

`Sys.which("python")`

If you have multiple python versions (or it is not in your path), then you can specify a different location with `use_python` for where the python binary is located and `use_conda` for the conda environment.

More info can be found in [this reticulate vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/vignettes/versions.html)

Answer (score 1):

For Conda Environment you may follow the screenshot attached.

User can go to **tools> global options> Python>Select the conda environment**.

[image: Click Here for the screenshot]