# install_keras() Error: Keras installation failed (no conda binary found)

Tags: r, keras, infopath2010

I am facing error in this command though I have python3 x in my system and have anaconda as well. I tried all the option given in 
[Error: Unable to find conda binary. Is Anaconda installed? reticulate Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52372425/error-unable-to-find-conda-binary-is-anaconda-installed-reticulate-rstudio/53434444#53434444)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53434444/revisions, but nothing working for me. 
In fact, I am getting error for H2o as well.

Warning in install.packages :

> **unable to move temporary installation** ‘C:\Users\kumaashi\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\file124f052421e1\h2o’ to ‘C:\Users\kumaashi\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\h2o’

I got this error earlier also but used to get fixed with `trace(utils:::unpackPkgZip, edit=TRUE)` by changing `sys.time` - 2.5 but **since i updated R** that option is not coming at all